# How to Avoid repeating Code

Tags: java, guice

I'm creating two Guice modules which handle different properties. The issue with this approach is that I have to duplicate the code two times in the implemenation. How can I avoid duplication and still be able to customize my bindings ?

I was thinking of using Providers but can't find a cleaner way to do it. Any direction would be appreciated

```
public abstract class AConfModule extends AbstractModule {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected void configure() {
        // Do some Confugurations
        iConfigure();
    }

    protected abstract void iConfigure();

}


public abstract class BConfModule extends AbstractModule {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected void configure() {
        // Do some Confugurations
        iConfigure();
    }

    protected abstract void iConfigure();

}
```

Comment: What about moving configure and iConfigure up into AbstractModule, or create another middle-man abstract ConfModule that extends AbstractModule?

Answer (score 4):

Why not:

```
public abstract class AbstractConfModule extends AbstractModule {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected void configure() {
        // Do some Configurations
        iConfigure();
    }

    protected abstract void iConfigure();

}

public abstract class AConfModule extends AbstractConfModule { }
public abstract class BConfModule extends AbstractConfModule { }
```

Comment: Is there any way to use Provider<T>  with the approch ?

Comment: @allthenutsandbolts what are you trying to do? Why do you want to use a Provider?

Comment: I have 2 modules one of which reads properties from command line and there is one module which actually reads from property files and Uses customized bindings. So I was thinking that if I introduced  a provider, I can then get the required type of module when needed.

Comment: Sounds like you're over engineering it. Just write the two config classes. Get them working. If after they are working you find some common code/pattern that can be refactored, then refactor. Otherwise move on to something else. There are far bigger fish to fry.

Comment: Even I thought so... Thanks